# Plotting with seaborn using the matplotlib object-oriented interface

Tags: python, oop, matplotlib, seaborn

I strongly prefer using `matplotlib` in OOP style:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
axarr[0].plot(...)
axarr[1].plot(...)
```

This makes it easier to keep track of multiple figures and subplots.

Question: How to use seaborn this way? Or, how to change [this example](http://www.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/anscombes_quartet.html) to OOP style? How to tell `seaborn` plotting functions like `lmplot` which `Figure` or `Axes` it plots to?

Comment: Related: [This issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/399) and 
 [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47624348/4124317) for a possible workaround, which would allow to create a seaborn figure and move all the axes to a subplot grid later.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

It depends a bit on which seaborn function you are using.

The plotting functions in seaborn are broadly [divided into two types](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions):

- "Axes-level" functions, including `regplot`, `boxplot`, `kdeplot`, and many others
- "Figure-level" functions, including `relplot`, `catplot`, `displot`, `pairplot`, `jointplot` and one or two others

The first group is identified by taking an explicit `ax` argument and returning an `Axes` object. As this suggests, you can use them in an "object oriented" style by passing your `Axes` to them:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
sns.regplot(x, y, ax=ax1)
sns.kdeplot(x, ax=ax2)
```

Axes-level functions will only draw onto an `Axes` and won't otherwise mess with the figure, so they can coexist perfectly happily in an object-oriented matplotlib script.

The second group of functions (Figure-level) are distinguished by the fact that the resulting plot can potentially include several Axes which are always organized in a "meaningful" way. That means that the functions need to have total control over the figure, so it isn't possible to plot, say, an `lmplot` onto one that already exists. Calling the function always initializes a figure and sets it up for the specific plot it's drawing.

However, once you've called `lmplot`, it will return an object of the type [`FacetGrid`](http://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html). This object has some methods for operating on the resulting plot that know a bit about the structure of the plot. It also exposes the underlying figure and array of axes at the `FacetGrid.fig` and `FacetGrid.axes` arguments. The `jointplot` function is very similar, but it uses a [`JointGrid`](http://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html#plotting-bivariate-data-with-jointgrid) object. So you can still use these functions in an object-oriented context, but all of your customization has to come after you've called the function.