# How do I plot a seaborn factorplot on a matplotlib subplot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, seaborn

For some reason, I just can't get this to work.  What I end up getting is two grids with axes plotted on top of each other and then the second plot plotted under this.  My code works fine for a seaborn distplot:

```
plt.subplot(121)
h = sns.distplot(dfmain["Runs"])

plt.subplot(122)
j = sns.distplot(dfHighScores["Runs"])
```

But if I try and plot two factor plots side by side (they are independent so I don't want the axes to be shared), then this just doesn't work as described above:

```
plt.subplot(121)
h = sns.factorplot("Runs",data=dfmain)

plt.subplot(122)
j = sns.factorplot("Runs",data=dfHighScores)
```

I get this behavior whether I use an iPython notebook or spyder as my IDE.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969619/plotting-with-seaborn-using-the-matplotlib-object-oriented-interface

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation of factorplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html#seaborn.factorplot) it should be able do draw two plots side by side by itself. If you combine both your data frames into one (and add a column to tell between them) then something like this should work:

```
 sns.factorplot("Runs", col="mainOrHighScores", data=dfCombined)
```

Otherwise I think factorplot doesn't operate on axes (unlike distplot).
In any case only functions that have an "ax" parameter for axes can draw on axes.