# plt.subplot make empty plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I would like to input 2 tables to fit in 1 row and 2 columns
so I set subplots (1, 2) but show (2, 2) shape with empty plots
(I use Jupyter notebook with `%matplotlib inline`)

How can I solve it?

```
f,ax=plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(20,8))

sns.barplot('SibSp','Survived',data=train, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_title('SibSp vs Survived')

sns.factorplot('SibSp','Survived',data=train, ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set_title('SibSp vs Survived')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `factorplot` creates its own figure and axes. You might instead want to use a [`pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925494/seaborn-produces-separate-figures-in-subplots)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `factorplot` function has been renamed to `catplot` in Seaborn.
But I think `catplot` doesn't take axes argument(not sure though).

The easiest way out is to use `pointplot` instead of `factorplot`.

```
f,ax=plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(20,8))

sns.barplot('SibSp','Survived',data=train, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_title('SibSp vs Survived')

sns.pointplot('SibSp','Survived',data=train, ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set_title('SibSp vs Survived')

plt.show()
```