# How to plot multiple Seaborn Jointplot in Subplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm having problem placing Seaborn `Jointplot` inside a multicolumn `subplot`.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': {'a': 1,'b': 15,'c': 9,'d': 7,'e': 2,'f': 2,'g': 6,'h': 5,'k': 5,'l': 8},
          'C2': {'a': 6,'b': 18,'c': 13,'d': 8,'e': 6,'f': 6,'g': 8,'h': 9,'k': 13,'l': 15}})

fig = plt.figure();   
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121);  
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122);

sns.jointplot("C1", "C2", data=df, kind='reg', ax=ax1)
sns.jointplot("C1", "C2", data=df, kind='kde', ax=ax2)
```

Notice how only a portion of the `jointplot` is placed inside the subplot and the rest left inside another two plot frames. What I'd want is to have both the `distributions` also inserted inside the `subplots`.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 74):

*Moving axes in matplotlib is not as easy as it used to be in previous versions. The below is working with the current version of matplotlib.*

As has been pointed out at several places ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969619/plotting-with-seaborn-using-the-matplotlib-object-oriented-interface), also [this issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/399)) several of the seaborn commands create their own figure automatically. This is hardcoded into the seaborn code, so there is currently no way to produce such plots in existing figures. Those are `PairGrid`, `FacetGrid`, `JointGrid`, `pairplot`, `jointplot` and `lmplot`.

There is a [seaborn fork available](https://github.com/bendichter/seaborn/tree/PairGrid_as_subplot) which would allow to supply a subplot grid to the respective classes such that the plot is created in a preexisting figure. To use this, you would need to copy the `axisgrid.py` from the fork to the seaborn folder. Note that this is currently restricted to be used with matplotlib 2.1 (possibly 2.0 as well).

An alternative could be to create a seaborn figure and copy the axes to another figure. The principle of this is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906599/4124317) and could be extended to Searborn plots. The implementation is a bit more complicated that I had initially expected. The following is a class `SeabornFig2Grid` that can be called with a seaborn grid instance (the return of any of the above commands), a matplotlib figure and a `subplot_spec`, which is a position of a `gridspec` grid.

Note: This is a **proof of concept**, it may work for most easy cases, but I would not recommend using it in production code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

class SeabornFig2Grid():

    def __init__(self, seaborngrid, fig,  subplot_spec):
        self.fig = fig
        self.sg = seaborngrid
        self.subplot = subplot_spec
        if isinstance(self.sg, sns.axisgrid.FacetGrid) or \
            isinstance(self.sg, sns.axisgrid.PairGrid):
            self._movegrid()
        elif isinstance(self.sg, sns.axisgrid.JointGrid):
            self._movejointgrid()
        self._finalize()

    def _movegrid(self):
        """ Move PairGrid or Facetgrid """
        self._resize()
        n = self.sg.axes.shape[0]
        m = self.sg.axes.shape[1]
        self.subgrid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(n,m, subplot_spec=self.subplot)
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(m):
                self._moveaxes(self.sg.axes[i,j], self.subgrid[i,j])

    def _movejointgrid(self):
        """ Move Jointgrid """
        h= self.sg.ax_joint.get_position().height
        h2= self.sg.ax_marg_x.get_position().height
        r = int(np.round(h/h2))
        self._resize()
        self.subgrid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(r+1,r+1, subplot_spec=self.subplot)

        self._moveaxes(self.sg.ax_joint, self.subgrid[1:, :-1])
        self._moveaxes(self.sg.ax_marg_x, self.subgrid[0, :-1])
        self._moveaxes(self.sg.ax_marg_y, self.subgrid[1:, -1])

    def _moveaxes(self, ax, gs):
        #https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906599/4124317
        ax.remove()
        ax.figure=self.fig
        self.fig.axes.append(ax)
        self.fig.add_axes(ax)
        ax._subplotspec = gs
        ax.set_position(gs.get_position(self.fig))
        ax.set_subplotspec(gs)

    def _finalize(self):
        plt.close(self.sg.fig)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("resize_event", self._resize)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def _resize(self, evt=None):
        self.sg.fig.set_size_inches(self.fig.get_size_inches())
```

The usage of this class would look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import SeabornFig2Grid as sfg


iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# An lmplot
g0 = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker", data=tips, 
                palette=dict(Yes="g", No="m"))
# A PairGrid
g1 = sns.PairGrid(iris, hue="species")
g1.map(plt.scatter, s=5)
# A FacetGrid
g2 = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time",  hue="smoker")
g2.map(plt.scatter, "total_bill", "tip", edgecolor="w")
# A JointGrid
g3 = sns.jointplot("sepal_width", "petal_length", data=iris,
                   kind="kde", space=0, color="g")


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,8))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

mg0 = sfg.SeabornFig2Grid(g0, fig, gs[0])
mg1 = sfg.SeabornFig2Grid(g1, fig, gs[1])
mg2 = sfg.SeabornFig2Grid(g2, fig, gs[3])
mg3 = sfg.SeabornFig2Grid(g3, fig, gs[2])

gs.tight_layout(fig)
#gs.update(top=0.7)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that there might be several drawbacks from copying axes and the above is not (yet) tested thoroughly.

Comment: What modifications would be needed for ClusterGrid?

Comment: @JackArnestad You would essentially need to recreate the grid used by seaborn. This would look similar to `_movejointgrid` but with four axes.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Would it be too much to ask for you to update the answer with this? I am a beginner to Python and matplotlib and am not exactly sure how to go about doing this. I would really appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: I think I remember not including clustergrid here because it would take almost as much code as creating the kind of plot manually.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I see. Could you suggest or show how that should be done? I'm stuck and would really appreciate and guidance.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest However, the colrbar (cbar=True) can't be shown in the subplots. Do you have any solution? (You can check my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966497/colorbar-not-shown-in-multiple-seaborn-jointplot))

Comment: @XinZhang Correct, this solution does not care about colorbar axes. Since this is quite involved, I would propose to create them manually afterwards.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest But, I couldn't get the xaxis and yaxis to enlarge the fontsize.

Comment: Update: `rc` and `font_scale` could solve the font problem.

Comment: The legends, however, are not showing. I could add them by `ax = plt.gca(); ax = plt.legend()`. But that puts the legend inside the plot, unlike the default position outside of the plot. Does any one know a remedy?

Comment: In matplotlib 3.4.0 (unreleased yet), they will support `subfigures`. This seems to be a good solution.

Comment: This is awesome! What is the easiest way to add titles to the subfigures? In my case, I was putting two jointplots side by side so managed to titles with `g1.ax_marg_x.set_title(...)`, but is their a more general way?

Comment: @JongsuLiamKim It seems that this still doesn't work trivially. See e.g. this example using subfigures where the three components are simply plotted separately. https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-matplotlib-subfigures-for-creating-complex-multi-panel-figures-70fa8f6c38a4

Answer (score 39):

It can not be easily done without hacking.  `jointplot` calls `JointGrid` method, which in turn creates a new `figure` object every time it is called.

Therefore, the hack is to make two jointplots (`JG1` `JG2`), then make a new figure, then migrate the axes objects from `JG1` `JG2` to the new figure created.

Finally, we adjust the sizes and the positions of subplots in the new figure we just created.

```
JG1 = sns.jointplot("C1", "C2", data=df, kind='reg')
JG2 = sns.jointplot("C1", "C2", data=df, kind='kde')

#subplots migration
f = plt.figure()
for J in [JG1, JG2]:
    for A in J.fig.axes:
        f._axstack.add(f._make_key(A), A)

#subplots size adjustment
f.axes[0].set_position([0.05, 0.05, 0.4,  0.4])
f.axes[1].set_position([0.05, 0.45, 0.4,  0.05])
f.axes[2].set_position([0.45, 0.05, 0.05, 0.4])
f.axes[3].set_position([0.55, 0.05, 0.4,  0.4])
f.axes[4].set_position([0.55, 0.45, 0.4,  0.05])
f.axes[5].set_position([0.95, 0.05, 0.05, 0.4])
```

It is a hack because we are now using `_axstack` and `_add_key` private methods, which might and might not stay the same as they are now in `matplotlib` future versions.

[image]

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine that going to all this trouble is a better idea than just setting up the subplot grid and drawing `distplot`, `regplot`, and `kdeplot` onto it.

Comment: Totally agree.  But reusability wise, doing so would mean to duplicate a lot of codes already written in `joint_plot`.  Maybe `JointGird` might take an optional parameter to specify plotting axes/axis.  Current behavior would mean that if one supply `ax=some_axis`, only the `regplot` plot will go to that `some_axis`.

Comment: That's just behavior that results from someone using the function in a way that was never intended.

Comment: @mwaskom How do you mean, " using the function in a way that was never intended"? Can you explain?

Comment: I am getting an error with this (seaborn version 0.11.2):
```python
      6 for J in [JG1, JG2]:
      7     for A in J.fig.axes:
----> 8         f._axstack.add(f._make_key(A), A)
     10 #subplots size adjustment
     11 f.axes[0].set_position([0.05, 0.05, 0.4,  0.4])

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute '_make_key'
```

Answer (score 7):

Recently, I'm developing [patchworklib](https://github.com/ponnhide/patchworklib), which is a subplot manager for matplotlib, inspired by patchwork.
It allows you to quickly arrange multiple gridded seaborn plots using only `/` and `|` operators.

Here is the example code, which [you can also run on Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1C1EN1-5L2QjnAAVo4vpx_i9knDRzX4jy?usp=sharing):

```py
import seaborn as sns
import patchworklib as pw 
sns.set_theme()
pw.overwrite_axisgrid() 

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# An lmplot
g0 = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker", data=tips, 
                palette=dict(Yes="g", No="m"))
g0 = pw.load_seaborngrid(g0, label="g0")

# A Pairplot
g1 = sns.pairplot(iris, hue="species")
g1 = pw.load_seaborngrid(g1, label="g1")

# A relplot
g2 = sns.relplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", col="time", hue="time", 
                 size="size", style="sex", palette=["b", "r"], sizes=(10, 100))
g2 = pw.load_seaborngrid(g2, label="g2")

# A JointGrid
g3 = sns.jointplot("sepal_width", "petal_length", data=iris,
                   kind="kde", space=0, color="g")

g3 = pw.load_seaborngrid(g3, label="g3")
(((g0|g1)["g0"]/g3)["g3"]|g2).savefig("seaborn_subplots.png")
```

[image: seaborn_subplots.png]

Answer (score 6):

If you get into trouble despite the elegant solution of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, you can still save seaborn plots to memory as images and use them to build your custom figure. Use other formats than '.png' if you seek a higher resolution.

Here is the example is shown above using this nasty (but working) approach:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# data
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

############### 1. CREATE PLOTS
# An lmplot
g0 = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker", data=tips, 
                palette=dict(Yes="g", No="m"))
# A PairGrid
g1 = sns.PairGrid(iris, hue="species")
g1.map(plt.scatter, s=5)
# A FacetGrid
g2 = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time",  hue="smoker")
g2.map(plt.scatter, "total_bill", "tip", edgecolor="w")
# A JointGrid
g3 = sns.jointplot("sepal_width", "petal_length", data=iris,
                   kind="kde", space=0, color="g")

############### 2. SAVE PLOTS IN MEMORY TEMPORALLY
g0.savefig('g0.png')
plt.close(g0.fig)

g1.savefig('g1.png')
plt.close(g1.fig)

g2.savefig('g2.png')
plt.close(g2.fig)

g3.savefig('g3.png')
plt.close(g3.fig)

############### 3. CREATE YOUR SUBPLOTS FROM TEMPORAL IMAGES
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(25, 16))

axarr[0,0].imshow(mpimg.imread('g0.png'))
axarr[0,1].imshow(mpimg.imread('g1.png'))
axarr[1,0].imshow(mpimg.imread('g3.png'))
axarr[1,1].imshow(mpimg.imread('g2.png'))

# turn off x and y axis
[ax.set_axis_off() for ax in axarr.ravel()]

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: The four subplots are shown together in the following image]

Comment: Why would someone want to save the files!!

Answer (score 0):

Following on @<https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest answer>. I have added an additional function ***_moveclustergrid*** to his Class to deal with seaborn's clusterheatmaps (**ClusterGrid** class).

```py
class SeabornFig2Grid():
    """Class from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535866/how-to-iteratively-populate-matplotlib-gridspec-with-a-multipart-seaborn-plot/47624348#47624348"""
    def __init__(self, seaborngrid, fig,  subplot_spec):
        self.fig = fig
        self.sg = seaborngrid
        self.subplot = subplot_spec
        if isinstance(self.sg, sns.axisgrid.FacetGrid) or \
            isinstance(self.sg, sns.axisgrid.PairGrid):
            self._movegrid()
        elif isinstance(self.sg, sns.axisgrid.JointGrid):
            self._movejointgrid()
        elif isinstance(self.sg, sns.matrix.ClusterGrid):
            self._moveclustergrid()
        else:
            print("what am i?")

        self._finalize()

    def _movegrid(self):
        """ Move PairGrid or Facetgrid """
        self._resize()
        n = self.sg.axes.shape[0]
        m = self.sg.axes.shape[1]
        self.subgrid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(n,m, subplot_spec=self.subplot)
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(m):
                self._moveaxes(self.sg.axes[i,j], self.subgrid[i,j])

    def _movejointgrid(self):
        """ Move Jointgrid """
        h= self.sg.ax_joint.get_position().height
        h2= self.sg.ax_marg_x.get_position().height
        r = int(np.round(h/h2))
        self._resize()
        self.subgrid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(r+1,r+1, subplot_spec=self.subplot)

        self._moveaxes(self.sg.ax_joint, self.subgrid[1:, :-1])
        self._moveaxes(self.sg.ax_marg_x, self.subgrid[0, :-1])
        self._moveaxes(self.sg.ax_marg_y, self.subgrid[1:, -1])

    def _moveclustergrid(self):
        """Move Cluster grid"""
        r = len(self.sg.figure.axes)
        self.subgrid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(r, r + 10, subplot_spec=self.subplot)
        subplots_axes = self.sg.figure.axes

        self._resize()
        self._moveaxes(subplots_axes[0], self.subgrid[1:, 0:3]) #left cladogram
        self._moveaxes(subplots_axes[1], self.subgrid[0, 4:-2]) #top cladogram
        self._moveaxes(subplots_axes[2], self.subgrid[1:, 3]) #labels bar
        self._moveaxes(subplots_axes[3], self.subgrid[1:, 4:-3]) #heatmap
        self._moveaxes(subplots_axes[4], self.subgrid[1:, -1]) #colorbar


    def _moveaxes(self, ax, gs):
        #https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906599/4124317
        ax.remove()
        ax.figure=self.fig
        self.fig.axes.append(ax)
        self.fig.add_axes(ax)
        ax._subplotspec = gs
        ax.set_position(gs.get_position(self.fig))
        ax.set_subplotspec(gs)

    def _finalize(self):
        plt.close(self.sg.fig)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("resize_event", self._resize)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def _resize(self, evt=None):
        self.sg.fig.set_size_inches(self.fig.get_size_inches())
```

It is not 100% "pretty-plot" proof, but it gives a place to start. Just change the locations of the subplots by modifying the number of rows and columns that they use in ***self.subgrid[rows,columns]***

Please see the output in the link (I do not have enough reputation to embed images): [clustermaps_side_by_side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S6kH.png)