# Add seaborn.palplot axes to existing figure for visualisation of different color palettes

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot, color-palette

Adding seaborn figures to subplots is [usually](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/cubehelix_palette.html) done by passing 'ax' when creating the figure. For instance:

```
sns.kdeplot(x, y, cmap=cmap, shade=True, cut=5, ax=ax)
```

This method, however, doesn't apply to [seaborn.palplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.palplot.html), which visualizes seaborn color palettes. My goal is to create a figure of different color palettes for scalable color comparison and presentation. This [image](https://i0.wp.com/edwards.sdsu.edu/research/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/seaborn_palettes.png?ssl=1) roughly shows the figure I'm trying to create [[source](https://edwards.sdsu.edu/research/python-dataviz-seaborn-heatmap-palettes/)].

A possibly related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664533/5511061) describes a method of creating a seaborn figure and copying the axes to another figure. I haven't been able to apply this method to the palplot figures, and would like to know if there is a quick way to force them into the existing figure.

Here's my minimum working example, now still generating separate figures.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
length, n_colors = 12, 50  # amount of subplots and colors per subplot
start_colors = np.linspace(0, 3, length)
for i, start_color in enumerate(start_colors):
    ax = fig1.add_subplot(length, 1, i + 1)
    colors = sns.cubehelix_palette(n_colors=n_colors, start=start_color,
                                   rot=0, light=0.4, dark=0.8)
    sns.palplot(colors)
plt.show(fig1)
```

Ultimately, to make the plot more informative, it would be great to print the RGB values stored in colors (list-like) evenly spaced over the palplots, but I don't know if this is easily implemented due to the unusual way of plotting in palplot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've probably already found, there's little documentation for the palplot function, but I've lifted directly from the [seaborn github repo](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/ceee0324f9b352c6d4aa9eb145d6ad3f5bcaad41/seaborn/miscplot.py) here:

```py
def palplot(pal, size=1):
    """Plot the values in a color palette as a horizontal array.
    Parameters
    ----------
    pal : sequence of matplotlib colors
        colors, i.e. as returned by seaborn.color_palette()
    size :
        scaling factor for size of plot
    """
    n = len(pal)
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(n * size, size))
    ax.imshow(np.arange(n).reshape(1, n),
              cmap=mpl.colors.ListedColormap(list(pal)),
              interpolation="nearest", aspect="auto")
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(n) - .5)
    ax.set_yticks([-.5, .5])
    # Ensure nice border between colors
    ax.set_xticklabels(["" for _ in range(n)])
    # The proper way to set no ticks
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.NullLocator())
```

So, it doesn't return any axes or figure objects, or allow you to specify an axes object to write into. You could make your own, as follows, by adding the ax argument and a conditional in case it's not provided. Depending on context, you may need the included imports as well.

```py
def my_palplot(pal, size=1, ax=None):
    """Plot the values in a color palette as a horizontal array.
    Parameters
    ----------
    pal : sequence of matplotlib colors
        colors, i.e. as returned by seaborn.color_palette()
    size :
        scaling factor for size of plot
    ax :
        an existing axes to use
    """

    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib as mpl
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

    n = len(pal)
    if ax is None:
        f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(n * size, size))
    ax.imshow(np.arange(n).reshape(1, n),
              cmap=mpl.colors.ListedColormap(list(pal)),
              interpolation="nearest", aspect="auto")
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(n) - .5)
    ax.set_yticks([-.5, .5])
    # Ensure nice border between colors
    ax.set_xticklabels(["" for _ in range(n)])
    # The proper way to set no ticks
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.NullLocator())
```

This function should work like you expect when you include the 'ax' argument. To implement this in your example:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
length, n_colors = 12, 50  # amount of subplots and colors per subplot
start_colors = np.linspace(0, 3, length)
for i, start_color in enumerate(start_colors):
    ax = fig1.add_subplot(length, 1, i + 1)
    colors = sns.cubehelix_palette(
        n_colors=n_colors, start=start_color, rot=0, light=0.4, dark=0.8
    )
    my_palplot(colors, ax=ax)
plt.show(fig1)
```

[image: example results]