# How to concatenate two `Facetgrid` plots?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

Using seaborn, I created two Facetgrid (`seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid`) plots as follows:

```
#load dataset
import pandas as pd
iris=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')

#plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

g1 = sns.FacetGrid(pd.melt(iris.loc[:,['sepal_length','sepal_width','species']], id_vars='species'), col='variable')
g1.map(sns.boxplot, 'species','value',order=['setosa','versicolor','virginia'])
g2 = sns.FacetGrid(iris, col="species")
g2.map(plt.scatter, "sepal_length", "sepal_width")
```

Two separate plots were generated:

[image]

and

[image]

I would like to have them in a single figure (and save as a single pdf file). However, I could not find any way to concatenate the plots (through python). I can always use Illustrator/Inkscape or bash commands to concatenate separate plots. However I want to avoid that and do all the steps in python alone.

I tried `fig.axes.append` (`fig.axes.append(g1.axes.flatten()[0])`), but the subplots ended up overlapping each other.

[image]

Question: Is it possible to concatenate two seaborn-Facegrid plots?

Comment: It's possible to get several seaborn FacetGrids in the same figure, but it's not the intended usage of FacetGrid. A solution is shown in [How to plot multiple Seaborn Jointplot in Subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042255/how-to-plot-multiple-seaborn-jointplot-in-subplot).

Comment: That solved my question. You could have *answered* the question rather than commenting.

Comment: If the answer to a question is given in another question, one does not answer this question, but instead mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Personally when I need to have multiple figures displayed together I will have an html output with embedded references to each of the plots I want to display. That way you can review the analysis all in one place on a browser.

Comment: I am trying to make multi-panel plots in python, similar to [`patchwork` module of R](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork).