# Scatterplot with contour heat overlay using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot, contour

I have a large series of data which includes >200k values.

The goal is to show the spread of the data and the rough trend rather than individual points. I would like to add a contour heat overlay, similar to this question, but using matplotlib, and with the option to specify the number of contours and their intervals:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/scatterplot-with-contour-heat-overlay

I hope this is clear. Please let me know if not!

Comment: seaborn's kdeplot produces a plot similar to the one in your example.

Comment: @KRKirov this looks good, but is there a way to specify the density at which you want to plot your contours?

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn's kdeplot will allow you to plot only shades rather than plotting all data points. The number of contours can be adjusted by specifying the n_levels parameter. For smaller data sets overlaying a jointplot and a kdeplot allows to display both data points and contour lines. The figure aesthetics can be varied widely, therefore I have compiled a few different options below. The subplot with the jointplots has been produced using the ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042255/how-to-plot-multiple-seaborn-jointplot-in-subplot).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
mean = [0, 0]
cov = [[50, 0], [0, 100]] 
x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 5000).T

# For large data sets
plt.subplots(1, 2)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(as_cmap=True, dark=0, light=1, reverse=True)
a = sns.kdeplot(x, y, n_levels=20, shade=True, cmap=cmap, gridsize=200, cbar=True)
a.set_xlabel('x')
a.set_ylabel('y')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
b = sns.kdeplot(x, y, n_levels=60, shade=True, gridsize=100, cmap="RdBu_r", cbar=True)
b.set_xlabel('x')
b.set_ylabel('y')
```

[image]

```
# For smaller data sets - jointplot and kdeplot overlayed. 
# Plain overlay
c = (sns.jointplot(x, y, color="g", marker='.').plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, n_levels=20)).set_axis_labels('x', 'y')
# with shade=True
d = (sns.jointplot(x, y, color="g").plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, n_levels=20, shade=True)).set_axis_labels('x', 'y')
# with transparency control, alpha=
e = (sns.jointplot(x, y, color="g", marker='.').plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, n_levels=20, shade=True, alpha=0.5)).set_axis_labels('x', 'y')
# diverging colour palette - blue to red
f = (sns.jointplot(x, y, marker='.').plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, n_levels=20, cmap="RdBu_r")).set_axis_labels('x', 'y')
# diverging colour palette and shade and reg
g = (sns.jointplot(x, y, marker='.', kind='reg').plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, n_levels=20, cmap="RdBu_r")).set_axis_labels('x', 'y')
# diverging colour palette, shade, 
h = (sns.jointplot(x, y).plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, n_levels=20, shade=True, cmap="RdBu_r")).set_axis_labels('x', 'y')
```

[image]