# Error plotting multiple Seaborn figures using SeabornFig2Grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I drew 4 Seaborn figures that I would like to put on a single figure using SeabornFig2Grid as proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042255/how-to-plot-multiple-seaborn-jointplot-in-subplot):

```
#%%
fig5 = sns.regplot(plotdata['Average precipitation in depth (mm per year)'],plotdata['Lifetime risk of maternal death (%)'], data=plotdata)
fig5 = sns.set(font_scale=1.4)
fig5 = plp.annotate('r-square = {0:.2f}'.format(r_value**2), (0.05, 0.8), xycoords='axes fraction')
fig5 = plp.annotate('y = {0:.2f} + {0:.2f} x Average precipitation in depth (mm/year)'.format(intercept1, slope1), (0.05, 0.9), xycoords='axes fraction')
fig5 = plt.gcf()
fig5.set_size_inches(10, 5)

fig6 = ....
fig7 = ....
fig8 = ....

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(45,25))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

mg0 = sfg.SeabornFig2Grid(fig5, fig, gs[0])
mg1 = sfg.SeabornFig2Grid(fig6, fig, gs[1])
mg2 = sfg.SeabornFig2Grid(fig7, fig, gs[2])
mg3 = sfg.SeabornFig2Grid(fig8, fig, gs[3])

gs.tight_layout(fig9)
#fig.savefig('fig9.jpg')
```

I wrote my code by adapting the example code provided for SeabornFig2Grid, but it returns the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-27-d3c8f9b3c3ea>", line 32, in <module>
    mg0 = sfg.SeabornFig2Grid(fig5, fig9, gs[0])

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\SeabornFig2Grid.py", line 17, in __init__
    self._finalize()

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\SeabornFig2Grid.py", line 52, in _finalize
    plt.close(self.sg.fig)

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'fig'
```

What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sns.regplot` does not return a figure, but an axes. For `regplot` you do not need to use the `SeabornFig2Grid` class. Instead you can directly plot it to an axes of the figure.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(45,25))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
sns.regplot(..., ax=ax5)
```