# Creating subplots of combined image and histogram from multiple Seaborn_images

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, raster, subplot

I'm trying to create a figure with three subplots of a combined raster image and histogram. I found a class called [seaborn_image](https://seaborn-image.sarthakjariwala.com/en/latest/api/imghist.html) with a function (seaborn_image.imghist) to plot an image and show the corresponding raster. However, I would like to plot three of these next to each other, but this turned out harder than it seemed.

The class does have this [method](https://seaborn-image.sarthakjariwala.com/en/latest/Tutorial/Image%20Collection.html) to create subplots, but this does not work for the `imghist` objects. This gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/margot/Documents/code/plot_rasters.py", line 542, in <module>
    isns.ImageGrid(imghist_col)

  File "/home/margot/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn_image/_grid.py", line 439, in __init__
    self._map_img_to_grid()

  File "/home/margot/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn_image/_grid.py", line 496, in _map_img_to_grid
    if _d.ndim > 2:

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'ndim'

<Figure size 1440x504 with 0 Axes>
```

I also looked into using the `SeabornFig2Grid` class from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042255/how-to-plot-multiple-seaborn-jointplot-in-subplot), using the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,7))
fig.subplots_adjust(top=1)
fig.suptitle('Crop rasters', fontsize=18)

nrows = 1
ncols = 3

imghist_s1 = isns.imghist(test_S1[test_key], aspect=2.2, cmap=batlow, dx=10, units='m') # pixelsize =10m
imghist_ndvi = isns.imghist(test_NDVI[test_key], aspect=2.2, vmin=0.1, vmax=0.95, cmap=batlow, dx=10, units='m') # pixelsize =10m
imghist_bp = isns.imghist(test_BP[test_key]/1000, aspect=2.2, vmin=0.1, vmax=0.95, cmap=batlow, dx=10, units='m') # pixelsize =10m

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows, ncols)

mg0 = SeabornFig2Grid(imghist_s1, fig, gs[0])
mg1 = SeabornFig2Grid(imghist_s1, fig, gs[1])
mg2 = SeabornFig2Grid(imghist_s1, fig, gs[2])

gs.tight_layout(fig)
plt.show()
```

But this gives me the same error as was posted in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726599/error-plotting-multiple-seaborn-figures-using-seabornfig2grid). Unfortunately, the given solution does not work for the seaborn_image class.

If this is not possible, I could also combine the images and histograms myself and then plot them as subplots. But I haven't found any suitable way to do this yet.

Can anyone help with the errors or does anyone have a suggestion how to approach the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should do `fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3); isns.imghist(..., ax=axs[0],...)` etc

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work with the `seaborn_image` package. I get `TypeError: seaborn_image._general.imgplot() got multiple values for keyword argument 'ax'`