# How to put Seaborn graphs into subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science

I want to put Sea born graphs into sub-plots using the following code. Can some body suggest the right approach?

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5)) 
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
sns.lmplot(data= df, x='Attack', y= 'Defense') 
plt.subplot(1,2,2) 
sns.jointplot(data= df, x='Attack', y= 'Defense', kind='scatter',color='purple') 
plt.show()
```

Comment: You need `ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)` and `sns.lmplot(...., ax=ax1)`. Same for ax2.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment you can not do it in a simple way. Some plots in `seaborn` are defined at the [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/introduction.html) (e.g. lmplot, factorplot, jointplot etc.) and they do not accept the axis argument.

If you really want to create subplots you can follow this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664533/8103056) which includes a support class (`SeabornFig2Grid`) to do exactly what you need. Here an example of that class in use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()


df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Attack = np.random.random(20),
    Defense = np.random.random(20)))

g0 = sns.lmplot(data= df, x='Attack', y= 'Defense') 
g1 = sns.jointplot(data= df, x='Attack', y= 'Defense', kind='scatter',color='purple') 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)

mg0 = SeabornFig2Grid(g0, fig, gs[0])
mg1 = SeabornFig2Grid(g1, fig, gs[1])

gs.tight_layout(fig)
```

[image]