# Add a table below a seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have seen a lot of stuff about this, but I cant seem to get any of it to work, so I thought I'd ask.

I would like to generate plots like this, with a table below the plot showing the count of each category.  Can anyone help me out?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {'Category': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
        'var1': [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7],
        'var2': [2, 4, 8, 9, 4, 2, 3, 8, 3, 7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.head(15))

sns.jointplot(data=df, x='var1', y='var2', hue='Category')

plt.suptitle('Example Data')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Ideally I'd like it to look something like this:

```
           Plot Stuff
     _______________________
    | Category | a | b | c |
    ------------------------
    |   Count  | 5 | 3 | 2 | 
    ------------------------
```

EDIT:

I've updated the script as shown below.  I cannot get the table centered, I can only get it to appear on the right side of the plot, and I NEED it to be under the plot, but above would also work.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {'Category': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
        'var1': [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7],
        'var2': [2, 4, 8, 9, 4, 2, 3, 8, 3, 7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.head(15))

sns.jointplot(data=df, x='var1', y='var2', hue='Category')

plt.suptitle('Example Data')

plt.table(cellText=df.values,
          rowLabels=df.index,
          colLabels=df.columns,
          cellLoc = 'center', rowLoc = 'center',
          loc='bottom')

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I find this answer to be very helpful.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042255/how-to-plot-multiple-seaborn-jointplot-in-subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042255/how-to-plot-multiple-seaborn-jointplot-in-subplot)

Comment: This matplotlib example explains how to add a table to a plot: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/table_demo.html

Comment: Also this -> https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-little-tables-with-matplotlib-9780ef5d0bc4

Comment: I'm still having problems placing the table where I want it. I saw those articles, but I can only get the table to appear on the right side of the plot.  I really need it above or preferably below the plot.   I think my trouble is that they are creating the data to use in the script.  I am reading my data in from a csv, which is why i set it up as a dataframe.  

Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bbox` to center your table manually, here is your code with `bbox` and adjusted font size:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {'Category': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
        'var1': [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7],
        'var2': [2, 4, 8, 9, 4, 2, 3, 8, 3, 7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.head(15))

sns.jointplot(data=df, x='var1', y='var2', hue='Category')

plt.suptitle('Example Data')

table = plt.table(cellText=df.values,
          rowLabels=df.index,
          colLabels=df.columns,
          bbox=(-6, -0.65, 6, 0.5))
table.auto_set_font_size(False)
table.set_fontsize(12)

plt.show()
```

[Picture of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aspbU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Complimenting @Fabian's answer:

it's possible to place `bbox` with respect to the figure, using [Transform](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) (`fig.transFigure` in this instance):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {'Category': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
        'var1': [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7],
        'var2': [2, 4, 8, 9, 4, 2, 3, 8, 3, 7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.head(15))

sns.jointplot(data=df, x='var1', y='var2', hue='Category')

plt.suptitle('Example Data')

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.4)

the_table = plt.table(cellText=df.values,
          rowLabels=df.index,
          colLabels=df.columns,
          cellLoc = 'center', rowLoc = 'center',
          transform=plt.gcf().transFigure,
          bbox = ([0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2]))
the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
the_table.set_fontsize(6)

plt.show()
```

[image]