# How to plot multiple Seaborn Jointplot with annotation in Subplot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, subplot

The objective is to create subplot for the  jointplot annotate with correlation. However, when `plt.show()`, the figure were displayed separately.

May I know how to solve this issue?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ncols=['ra','rb','a','b','c','d']

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,len(ncols)),columns=ncols)
nvars=['a','b','c','d']
rt=['a','b']
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(rt),len(nvars))
for idx_rt, nrt in enumerate(rt):
  for idx_var, nvar  in enumerate(nvars):
    g=sns.jointplot(data=df, y=nrt, x=nvar,kind = 'reg',ax=axs[idx_rt,idx_var])
    r, p = stats.pearsonr(df[nrt], df[nvar])
    g.ax_joint.annotate(f'$\\rho = {r:.3f}, p = {p:.3f}$',
      xy=(0.1, 0.9), xycoords='axes fraction',
      ha='left', va='center',
      bbox={'boxstyle': 'round', 'fc': 'powderblue', 'ec': 'navy'})
    

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042255/how-to-plot-multiple-seaborn-jointplot-in-subplot) to be very helpful

Comment: the `TypeError` is because you have an extra comma after `ax`. Replacing by `for ax in axes.flat:` avoid the error (although doesn't plot on the same grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on top of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664533/7678074) you should succeed by combining a custom `SeabornFig2Grid` class and matplotlib `GridSpec`. Here's your toy example:

- first define the **SeabornFig2Grid** class

  class SeabornFig2Grid():

  ```
   def __init__(self, seaborngrid, fig,  subplot_spec):
       self.fig = fig
       self.sg = seaborngrid
       self.subplot = subplot_spec
       if isinstance(self.sg, sns.axisgrid.FacetGrid) or \
           isinstance(self.sg, sns.axisgrid.PairGrid):
           self._movegrid()
       elif isinstance(self.sg, sns.axisgrid.JointGrid):
           self._movejointgrid()
       self._finalize()

   def _movegrid(self):
       """ Move PairGrid or Facetgrid """
       self._resize()
       n = self.sg.axes.shape[0]
       m = self.sg.axes.shape[1]
       self.subgrid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(n,m, subplot_spec=self.subplot)
       for i in range(n):
           for j in range(m):
               self._moveaxes(self.sg.axes[i,j], self.subgrid[i,j])

   def _movejointgrid(self):
       """ Move Jointgrid """
       h= self.sg.ax_joint.get_position().height
       h2= self.sg.ax_marg_x.get_position().height
       r = int(np.round(h/h2))
       self._resize()
       self.subgrid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(r+1,r+1, subplot_spec=self.subplot)

       self._moveaxes(self.sg.ax_joint, self.subgrid[1:, :-1])
       self._moveaxes(self.sg.ax_marg_x, self.subgrid[0, :-1])
       self._moveaxes(self.sg.ax_marg_y, self.subgrid[1:, -1])

   def _moveaxes(self, ax, gs):
       #https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906599/4124317
       ax.remove()
       ax.figure=self.fig
       self.fig.axes.append(ax)
       self.fig.add_axes(ax)
       ax._subplotspec = gs
       ax.set_position(gs.get_position(self.fig))
       ax.set_subplotspec(gs)

   def _finalize(self):
       plt.close(self.sg.fig)
       self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("resize_event", self._resize)
       self.fig.canvas.draw()

   def _resize(self, evt=None):
       self.sg.fig.set_size_inches(self.fig.get_size_inches())
  ```
- then draw your plots in the same grid

```
import itertools 
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
# import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ncols=['ra','rb','a','b','c','d']

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,len(ncols)),columns=ncols)
nvars=['a','b','c','d']
rt=['a','b']

# A JointGrid
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,8))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(len(rt),len(nvars))

for i, idxs in enumerate(itertools.product(rt, nvars)):
    nrt, nvar = idxs
    g=sns.jointplot(data=df, y=nrt, x=nvar,kind = 'reg')#, space=0,ax=axs[idx_rt,idx_var])
    r, p = stats.pearsonr(df[nrt], df[nvar])
    g.ax_joint.annotate(f'$\\rho = {r:.3f}, p = {p:.3f}$',
      xy=(0.1, 0.9), xycoords='axes fraction',
      ha='left', va='center',
      bbox={'boxstyle': 'round', 'fc': 'powderblue', 'ec': 'navy'})
    mg = SeabornFig2Grid(g, fig, gs[i])

gs.tight_layout(fig)
#gs.update(top=0.7)

plt.show()
```

The results is as follows:
[image]

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @rpb does this answer your question?