# how to add multiple seaborn subplots to one figure

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042255/how-to-plot-multiple-seaborn-jointplot-in-subplot/47664533#47664533)

I'm trying to add in the color bar legends to a seaborn jointplot to the overal SeabornFig2Grid. Here is the code and output, as you can see the color bars are overlapping the 2d histograms, and the right label of the color bar is cut off.

I've tried using `plt.subplots_adjust`, or `ax.ax_joint.set_position` / `ax.set_position`, but with no luck.

I've updated `SeabornFig2Grid` from the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042255/how-to-plot-multiple-seaborn-jointplot-in-subplot/47664533#47664533) to include the method `_moveaxis` so that the color bar could be added.

here is the code

```py
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

class SeabornFig2Grid():
    """Allow seaborn figure-level figs to be suplots.
    
    thanks - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042255/how-to-plot-multiple-seaborn-jointplot-in-subplot/47664533#47664533
    """
    
    def __init__(self, seaborngrid, fig,  subplot_spec):
        
        self.fig = fig
        self.sg = seaborngrid
        self.subplot = subplot_spec
        if isinstance(self.sg, sns.axisgrid.FacetGrid) or \
            isinstance(self.sg, sns.axisgrid.PairGrid):
            self._movegrid()
        elif isinstance(self.sg, sns.axisgrid.JointGrid):
            self._movejointgrid()
        elif isinstance(self.sg, matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes):
            self._moveaxis()
        self._finalize()
        pass
    
    def _moveaxis(self):
        self._resize()
        self.subgrid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 1, subplot_spec=self.subplot)
        self._moveaxes(self.sg, self.subgrid[0, 0])

    def _movegrid(self):
        """Move PairGrid or Facetgrid."""
        self._resize()
        n = self.sg.axes.shape[0]
        m = self.sg.axes.shape[1]
        self.subgrid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(n, m, subplot_spec=self.subplot)
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(m):
                self._moveaxes(self.sg.axes[i, j], self.subgrid[i, j])
        pass

    def _movejointgrid(self):
        """Move Jointgrid."""
        h = self.sg.ax_joint.get_position().height
        h2 = self.sg.ax_marg_x.get_position().height
        r = int(np.round(h / h2))
        self._resize()
        self.subgrid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(r + 1, r + 1, subplot_spec=self.subplot)

        self._moveaxes(self.sg.ax_joint, self.subgrid[1:, :-1])
        self._moveaxes(self.sg.ax_marg_x, self.subgrid[0, :-1])
        self._moveaxes(self.sg.ax_marg_y, self.subgrid[1:, -1])
        pass

    def _moveaxes(self, ax, grid_spec):

        ax.remove()
        ax.figure = self.fig
        self.fig.axes.append(ax)
        self.fig.add_axes(ax)
        ax._subplotspec = grid_spec
        ax.set_position(grid_spec.get_position(self.fig))
        try:
            ax.set_subplotspec(grid_spec)
        except AttributeError:
            ax._subplotspec = grid_spec
        pass

    def _finalize(self):
        try:
            plt.close(self.sg.fig)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("resize_event", self._resize)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        pass

    def _resize(self, evt=None):
        self.sg.figure.set_size_inches(self.fig.get_size_inches())
        pass
    
    pass


# create data
x = [np.random.random() for x in range(1000)]
y = [np.random.random() for x in range(1000)]

# add 2d-hist and color bars to `axes` list
axes = []
for i in range(2):
    # create 2d histogram
    ax1 = sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, marginal_kws={'bins' : 20})
    ax1.ax_joint.cla()
    ax1.fig.set_size_inches((5, 4))
    plt.sca(ax1.ax_joint)
    plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=20, norm=mcolors.LogNorm(*(None, None)), cmap='jet')

    # set up scale bar legend
    cbar_ax = ax1.fig.add_axes([1, 0.1, 0.03, 0.7])
    cb = plt.colorbar(cax=cbar_ax)
    cb.set_label(r"$\log_{10}$ density of points", fontsize=13)

    axes.extend([ax1, cbar_ax])

# adjust gridspec so ratios are more visually appealing
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, len(axes), width_ratios=[1, 0.1] * int(len(axes) / 2))

# add axes to SeabornFig2Grid
for ax, g in zip(axes, gs):
    _ = SeabornFig2Grid(ax, fig, g)
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the `h` in `_moveaxis` supposed to be used for?

Comment: sorry @jared, that was a line of code that i forgot to remove. I've removed it. (It was related to the `_movejointgrid` when I was building `_moveaxis`, but I didn't need it)

Comment: Can you get this to work with just one plot in a figure?  If so, you could use subfigures: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html

Comment: @JodyKlymak no unfortunately this won't work with a seaborn figure. You can't pass an axes subplot to sns.jointplot.

Comment: Can you pass a figure?

Comment: @JodyKlymak not that I can tell from documentation. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html

Comment: This seems like a pretty straightforward thing for seaborn to add

Comment: I also posted the answer here(https://stackoverflow.com/a/70816718/18004774), but I believe the issue can be resolved by using the patchworklib I developed previously. How about that?