# Multiple graphs on the same plot in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a bar style "factorplot" for some data, then plot a regular point style "factorplot" for my fit of that data on top of it. So for the data plot I can simply do :

```
sns.factorplot(x='x',y='yData',data=dataFrame,kind='bar')
```

And for the model plot I can simply do :

```
sns.factorplot(x='x',y='yModel',data=dataFrame,kind='point')
```

The problem is that if I then do :

```
sns.plt.show()
```

I get 2 separate figures instead of just one. Is there any simple way to tell seaborn to just plot them on the same graph ?

Comment: Not sure it is the solution bug if you do `g = sns.factorplot(x='x',y='yData',data=dataFrame,kind='bar')`, then `g` will be a `FacetGrid`, maybe you can use these axes (`g.ax`) for the next factorplot ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting with seaborn using the matplotlib object-oriented interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969619/plotting-with-seaborn-using-the-matplotlib-object-oriented-interface)

Comment: @mgc I don't think that's possible for a factor plot

Comment: @mwaskom This certainly enlightens me somewhat as to what's going on, I guess I'll try to go from there and find my own solution, perhaps ditching factorplot for an "axes-level" fucntion, but I'll keep the question up in case someone has something else in mind.

Comment: You might be lucky to get any other ideas - mwaskom is, I believe, the author and maintainer of seaborn...

Comment: @JRichardSnape Oh well, back to regular pyplot for this task then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969619/plotting-with-seaborn-using-the-matplotlib-object-oriented-interface) explains the basic architecture that accounts for why you see that behavior (two different figures), but it's possible to give a more specific answer to your question:

The [tutorial](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical.html) explains that `factorplot` is mostly a convenience function that combines `FacetGrid` with a number of Axes-level functions for drawing categorical plots that share an API. Since you aren't using the faceting options of `factorplot`, all you need to do is replace `sns.factorplot(..., kind="bar")` with `sns.barplot(...)` and `sns.factorplot(..., kind="point")` with `sns.pointplot(...)`.