# Plotting a boxplot and histogram side by side with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a simple box plot next to a simple histogram in the same figure using seaborn (0.11.2) and pandas (1.3.4) in a jupyter notebook (6.4.5).

I've tried multiple approaches with nothing working.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
sns.boxplot(x='rent', data=df, ax=ax[0])
sns.displot(x='rent', data=df, bins=50, ax=ax[1])
```

[image: adds extra grid next to the boxplot.]

There is an extra plot or grid that gets put next to the boxplot, and this extra empty plot shows up any time I try to create multiple axes.

Changing:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)
```

Gets:

[image: The extra empty plot is now on the bottom]

Again, that extra empty plot next to the boxplot, but this time below it.

Trying the following code:

```
fig, (axbox, axhist) = plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.boxplot(x='rent', data=df, ax=axbox)
sns.displot(x='rent', data=df, bins=50, ax=axhist)
```

Gets the same results.

Following the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082602/plotting-multiple-different-plots-in-one-figure-using-seaborn), I try:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
sns.boxplot(x='rent', data=df, ax=axs[0])
sns.displot(x='rent', data=df, bins-50, ax=axs[1])
```

results in the same thing:

[image]

If I just create the figure and then the plots underneath:

```
plt.figure()
sns.boxplot(x='rent', data=df)
sns.displot(x='rent', data=df, bins=50)
```

It just gives me the two plots on top of each other, which I assume is just making two different figures.

I'm not sure why that extra empty plot shows up next to the boxplot when I try to do multiple axes in seaborn.

If I use pyplot instead of seaborn, I can get it to work:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
ax1.hist(df['rent'], bins=50)
ax2.boxplot(df['rent'])
```

Results in:

[image: Two plots on one figure]

The closest I've come is to use seaborn only on the boxplot, and pyplot for the histogram:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
sns.boxplot(x='rent', data=df)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.hist(df['rent'], bins=50)
```

Results:

[image: Two plots, one figure.]

What am I missing? Why can't I get this to work with two seaborn plots on the same figure, side by side (1 row, 2 columns)?

Comment: I find [seaborn is not plotting within defined subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63895392/seaborn-is-not-plotting-within-defined-subplots) to be very helpful. Try this:`sns.histplot(x='rent', data=df, bins=50, ax=ax[1])`

Comment: Thank you. That indeed did exactly what I needed it to, and now I know to use histplot when plotting with multiple axes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
def creating_box_hist(column, df):
    # creating a figure composed of two matplotlib.Axes objects (ax_box and ax_hist)
    f, (ax_box, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (.15, .85)})    

    # assigning a graph to each ax
    sns.boxplot(df[column], ax=ax_box)
    sns.histplot(data=df, x=column, ax=ax_hist)

    # Remove x axis name for the boxplot
    ax_box.set(xlabel='')
    plt.show()
```