# inner() got multiple values for argument 'ax'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

In a Jupyter notebook with Python I am plotting a hexbin jointplot from two columns of a dataframe. The plot is correctly plotted but I cant manage to resize the picture.

Here is the code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(11.7, 8.27)
sns.jointplot(x=train['max1'], y=train['intangle'], kind="hex", color="#4CB391",ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

gut I get inner() got multiple values for argument 'ax'

Comment: Full traceback, please

Comment: ...and a [mcve] of the issue. Otherwise this is off-topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that jointplot [creates its own figure and axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969619/plotting-with-seaborn-using-the-matplotlib-object-oriented-interface). It therefore does not have an `ax` argument available. Also the size of the figure is always squared. To change the size, use the `size` argument.

```
sns.jointplot(..., size=10)
plt.show()
```

Or, change the figure size afterwards,

```
g = sns.jointplot(...)
g.fig.set_size_inches(11,6)
plt.show()
```