# How to plot independent graphs next to each other using seaborn?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

my problem is that I could only find answers for plots sharing the same y-axis units.

My graphs are defined as follows:

```
#Plot1
sns.set_style("white")
sns.catplot(y="Reaction_cd_positive", x="Flux_cd_positive", 
            kind="bar",height=4, data=CDP,aspect=1.5)
#Plot2
sns.catplot(y="Reaction_cd_negative",x="Flux_cd_negative",
            kind="bar",height=4, data=CDN, aspect=1.5)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the desired outcome? Can you describe in more than 0 words what you want to achieve?

Comment: The outcome should be as specified in the title. By default the graphs are plotted one under another; I want them to be right next to each other (by chance even four or more).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me translate this. You are using seaborn in a jupyter notebook. You want 2 barplots next to each other within the same figure, instead of two individual figures. Since `catplot` produces a figure by itself, there are two options.

1. Create a single `catplot` with two subplots. To this end you would need to concatenate your two DataFrames into a single one, then use the `col` argument to split the data into the two subplots.
2. Create a subplot grid with matplotlib first, then plot a `barplot` into each of the subplots. This is shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969619/plotting-with-seaborn-using-the-matplotlib-object-oriented-interface).