# How to plot seaborn pairplot as subplot?

Tags: seaborn, subplot

I use the following to create my subplots

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)
sns.plotfunc(..., ax = axs[0])
```

but, the **pairplot** function in seaborn does not support the **ax augment**, any idea how to plot it as subplot?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting with seaborn using the matplotlib object-oriented interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969619/plotting-with-seaborn-using-the-matplotlib-object-oriented-interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if I passed `plt.subplots(2, 2)`, it will return 2*2 array, thus I should use `sns.plotfunc(..., ax = axs[0][1])`, instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use Seaborn's [PairGrid](http://%20https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html) to plot multiple pairplots like this:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(df, y_vars=['variable_a','variable_b'], x_vars=["variable_c", "variable_d"], height=4)
g.map(sns.regplot)
plt.show()
```

Another example on how to use PairGrid can be found [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html).