# for loop with seaborn not displaying all plots

Tags: python, for-loop, seaborn, databricks

I've been trying to plot multiple graphs using a for loop and seaborn. Have tried different approaches (with subplots and trying to display them sequentially) and I can't manage to get the all the graphs to display (the best I've achieved is plotting the last one in the list). Here are the two approaches I've tried:

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharex = True) #Just hardcoding thre 3 here (number of slicers to plot) for testing

```
for i, col in enumerate(slicers): 
  plt.sca(ax[i])
  ax[i] = sns.catplot(x = 'seq', kind = 'count', hue = col
  , order = dfFirst['seq'].value_counts().index, height=6, aspect=11.7/6
  , data = dfFirst) # distribution.set_xticklabels(rotation=65,                                    horizontalalignment='right')
display(fig)
```

Have tried all combinations between plt.sca(ax[i]) and ax[i] = sns.catplot (activating both as in the example and one at a time) but fig always shows empty when displaying. In addition, I tried displaying figures sequentially using:

```
for i, col in enumerate(slicers):
  plt.figure(i)
  sns.catplot(x = 'seq', kind = 'count', hue = col
  , order = dfFirst['seq'].value_counts().index, height=6, aspect=11.7/6
  , data = dfFirst) # distribution.set_xticklabels(rotation=65,   horizontalalignment='right')
  display(figure)
```

Answer (score 1):

`catplot` produces its own figure. See [Plotting with seaborn using the matplotlib object-oriented interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969619/plotting-with-seaborn-using-the-matplotlib-object-oriented-interface)

Hence, here it's just

```
for whatever:
    sns.catplot(...)

plt.show()
```