# How Add Average Values to a Categorical Plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, catplot

Trying to add the average value to each category in the plot. I have been trying to add these average values independently, per category, but without success. Is there a way that catplot can average the values from the data set and plot that extra value with a different color? My goal is to add and differentiate the average value from the individual values so can be visually identified.

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [5.50, 5.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

ax = sns.catplot(x="Sample Set", y="Values [%]", data=df)
ax.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
ax.despine(right=True, top=True)

sp = 100
delta = 5
plt.axhline(y=sp, color='gray', linestyle='--', label='Target')

plt.axhline(y=sp*((100+(delta*2))/100), color='r', linestyle='--', label='10%')
plt.axhline(y=sp*((100-(delta*2))/100), color='r', linestyle='--')

plt.ylim(80, 120)
plt.title('Sample Location[enter image description here][1]', fontsize = 14, y=1.05)
    
plt.legend(frameon=False, loc ="lower right")
plt.savefig(outputFileName, dpi=300, bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.show()
plt.draw()
```

[image: Current Output from Code]

Comment: You might be able to create a `catplot` with the average values excluded, then superimpose the mean values

Comment: @DerekO like the idea, my only constraint right now after implementing what you are proposing is adding a legend that accounts for the dash lines, individual values, and the avg value. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't have enough time to make a serious attempt at a solution, so I left my idea as a comment to hopefully help either you or someone else get started on a solution. when i have a bit more time, i'd be happy to revisit your question and see if I can help further

Comment: @DerekO, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably run into strange error messages, as you named the return value of `sns.catplot` as `ax`.  [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) is a ["figure-level"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) function and returns a `FacetGrid`, often assigned to a variable named `g`. A figure-level function can have one or more subplots, accessible via `g.axes`. When there is only one subplot, `g.ax` points to that subplot.

Also note that the `catplot`'s figsize isn't set via the `rcParams`. The figure size comes from the `height=` parameter (height in inches of one subplot) and the `aspect=` parameter (ratio between width and height of a subplot), multiplied by the number of rows/columns of subplots.

Further, you seem to be mixing the ["object-oriented"](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) and the pyplot interface for matplotlib.  For readability and code maintenance, it is preferred to stick to one interface.

To indicate the means, `sns.pointplot` without confidence interval might be suited. `ax.axhspan` might be used to visualize the range around the target.

Here is some example code starting from seaborn's iris dataset.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

g = sns.catplot(data=iris, x="species", y="sepal_length", height=5.50, aspect=1)
ax = g.ax
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=0, length=0)
sns.pointplot(data=iris, x="species", y="sepal_length", estimator=np.mean,
              join=False, ci=None, markers=['D'], color='black', size=20, zorder=3, ax=ax)
sns.despine(right=True, top=True)

sp = 6
delta = 10
ax.axhline(y=sp, color='gray', linestyle='--', label='Target')
ax.axhspan(ymin=sp * (100 - delta) / 100, ymax=sp * (100 + delta) / 100,
           color='r', alpha=0.15, linestyle='--', label='10%')

ax.collections[-1].set_label('Mean')
ax.legend(frameon=False, loc="lower right")
# plt.savefig(outputFileName, dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: catplot with means]

Comment: thanks for your help and advice. Really well appreciated!

Comment: I will since it really attacks the problem as stated. However, the only missing part is how to add the legend for the average values. I have been trying to use the label approach within the point plot function but did not work.

Comment: Seaborn and legends are often complicated, as typical functions combine many matplotlib elements.  In this case, `ax.collections[-1].set_label('Mean')` adds a label to the collection that contains the means.

Comment: Thanks for your help JohanC! That's works nicely.

Answer (score -1):

According to [plotting with seaborn using the matplotlib object-oriented interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23973562/11381650) as `catplot` is a `Figure-level`type of graph, will be much harder than doing it comparing to some other types of graph.

> The second group of functions (Figure-level) are distinguished by the
> fact that the resulting plot can potentially include several Axes
> which are always organized in a "meaningful" way. That means that the
> functions need to have total control over the figure, so it isn't
> possible to plot, say, an lmplot onto one that already exists. Calling
> the function always initializes a figure and sets it up for the
> specific plot it's drawing.